# Equivalent definition of an "attractor"

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a topological space, $\tau:\Omega\to\Omega$, $\operatorname{Orb}(\tau,U):=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\tau^n(U)$ for $U\subseteq\Omega$, $A\subseteq\Omega$ and$^1$ $$E(A):=\left\{x\in\Omega\mid\forall N\in\mathcal N(A):\exists n_0\in\mathbb N_0:\forall n\ge n_0:\tau^n(x)\in N\right\}.$$

$U\in\mathcal N(A)$ is called *fundamenal neighbhorhood of $A$* if $$\forall N\in\mathcal N(A):\exists n_0\in\mathbb N_0:\operatorname{Orb}(\tau\circ\tau^{n_0},U)\subseteq N\tag1.$$ Moreover, $A$ is called

1. *attracting* if $\exists U\in\mathcal N(A):U\subseteq E(A)$;
2. *stable* if $$\forall N\in\mathcal N(A):\exists U\in\mathcal N(A):\operatorname{Orb}(\tau,U)\subseteq N\tag2;$$
3. *asymptotic stable* if $A$ is attracting and stable;
4. *attractor* if $A$ is forward invariant and asymptotic stable.

If $A$ is forward invariant, I've read that (assuming that $A$ is compact, but I actually don't see why this should matter) $A$ is an attractor if and only if $A$ has a fundamental neighborhood $U$.

Are we really able to show this?

The condition in $(1)$ ensures that $A$ is somehow "eventually stable". On the one hand, it is a stronger condition than $(2)$, since $U$ doesn't depend on $N$. On the other hand, it is weaker, since it only "becomes stable" at time $n_0$ (and as if this wasn't bad enough, $n_0$ depends on $N$).

So, if I'm not missing something neither should $(1)$ imply $(2)$ nor should $(2)$ imply $(1)$. Thus, if the claim is true, the crucial ingredient must be the forward invariance or the compactness.

---

$^1$ $\mathcal N(A)$ denotes the set of neighborhoods of $A$.

Comment: Try taking a collection of countably many $I_n = [0,1)$ and glue them all together at $0$, and then define $\tau$ on each one to be $\tau(x) = x^{1+1/n}$. I think you shouldn't be able to build a fundamental neighborhood since every point goes to $0$ at a different rate, but it should still be attracting and stable.

Comment: @User203940 Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure whether we really cannot find a fundamental neighborhood in your example. However, do you got doubts for the other direction as well?